# Classroom API getMaterials not returning materiels under topics

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-classroom

i'm trying to get Materials listed under a specific topic using google Classroom API, but what i get is only materials that are listed directly under CourseWork, once i move them to a topic getMaterials returns null;
i also tried this to get json returned by the server :

`mClassroomService.courses().courseWork().list(courseID).execute().getCourseWork().toString()`

the result confirmed that only courseWorks that are not listed under a certain topic that get loaded with their material.
any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Currently it is not possible to retrieve "independent" materials with [courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list)

The respective endpoint has not been implemented so far.

However, other users who are also affected by this issue filed a 
[feature request](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/115421140) for this behavior on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

If you "star" this feature request, you will help to increase visibility for the importance of this feature and thus the chance that it will be implemented in the near future.